# Garbage collector too slow on app with LargeHeap

Tags: java, android, memory, garbage-collection

When I started working on my project, I had no idea how to program and was just learning as I went along. My program requires a lot of bitmap graphics and I ran into memory issues early on. I enabled LargeHeap in my app manifest to allow me to use more memory for the graphics, but since then I've learned more about how android handles memory with garbage collector. I made small demo apps to test that GC could keep up with the rate I changed bitmaps and everything worked fine.

But when I try to utilize GC inside my big project, which now has a ridiculous heap of 170mb (the program isn't for general use, so the heap isn't really a concern...I'm just being picky), the memory consumption builds and builds. I've noticed some strange behavior from android in my app in the past that I eventually put down to "the program is probably just too big for the system", so I was wondering if it makes sense to believe that my program is too big or intensive for Garbage Collector to do its thing fast enough? I mean, 170mb heap for an app is  ridiculous enough, right?

EDIT - I'm thinking that a possible solution to the problem, and an answer to my question would come from rewriting the whole program to take advantage of GC. But, as I said, that would involve rewriting the WHOLE thing!! - So I'd rather not bother :D

Comment: What size are your bitmaps and what do you do with them?

Comment: When you say "the memory consumption builds and builds" are you sure you don't have a memory leak somewhere?

Comment: @mario There isn't a leak in the rest of the program, everything runs sound without this new section of code. There is a leak, but the memory is leaking because GC is failing to collect my unused Bitmaps. In the demo program, the code it almost identical and GC works fine.

Comment: @Demonick The bitmaps are 1280x751 (tailored for the tablet I'm working on). They're just displayed on the screen when called and then removed when the user is done looking at them. The demo application is able to do this with no fuss and no memory build-up. The only difference is the amount of currently being used by either app. The demo is like 6mb, or something...

Comment: What happens if you call System.gc() explicitly after you recycle your images, does it work? (Just for test, you generally never need to explicitly call the gc)

Comment: @mario I don't have to do this on the demo app, but I've had to recycle different bitmaps in my large program before so I tried this right away. It doesn't work, but it DOES work on my older code when I'm recycling much smaller images (100x100). This also leads me to believe that it's just a shortcoming of the system. The images are pretty big and the system already has a lot going on.

Comment: I've not got that much experience with the GC system in Android, but if you're holding references to these images, are you setting them to `null` once you've removed them? IIRC this can help to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: What happens if you re-use your imagines as much as possible instead of discarding them.

Comment: @Closeratio Yeah I've nulled the hell out of them. Went on a null spree :D

Comment: @PeterLawrey I'm not sure I understand what you mean by 're-use' them? Do you mean the bitmap variable? Because I use the same one for all the images. There's only one image displayed at once so I load it, then null the bitmap, then load a new one into the same variable.

Comment: Can you use the same Bitmap object, not just the same variable? If you can do that it won't create any garbage.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I'm not sure what the difference is. Are you talking about the object that displays the image? I'm only use one of those as well. I've tried using the same one over and over and I've also tried destroying it with the variable. I make the bitmap variable and then determine which of various buttons were pressed to decide from which location to load the image. The imageview then displays that image until I close it. At which point I've tried combinations of destroying the imageview and the bitmap variable.

Comment: Have you tried not destroying the image but reusing them?

Comment: "It doesn't work, but it DOES work on my older code when I'm recycling much smaller images (100x100). This also *leads me to believe that it's just a shortcoming of the system*" Funny, that's the exact *opposite* of what it would lead me to believe. Especially if this were my first large program.

Comment: And, as a side note, it would help if you showed your actual code: where you're allocating the bitmaps, and where you're explicitly nulling them. As well as anything that uses them in the middle.

Comment: @parsifal In my program, I am recycling bitmaps in two different sections. In a section I wrote a few months ago, I'm only recycling images that are 100x100 and it works perfectly. Today I've added a new section where I have tried to recycle larger images. Since I have seen my code work in two other places (the demo app that uses the same large images and earlier in my big app code that uses the smaller images), I've come to the conclusion that the combination of the large images in the large app is too much to ask. I thought that was reasonable. What would you conclude?

Comment: @parsifal I'd typically agree about showing the code, I know it's difficult to help when you can't see the issue. However I wasn't expecting you guys to try and correct the code for me. I've used it before so I believe it to work. I was actually looking for some sort of confirmation of my suspicion or a different theory that would explain what I'm seeing. As far as I'm concerned, I'm asking a lot of a mobile OS - just wanted to know if anyone had seen similar behaviour.

Comment: @user1537360 - knowing that thousands of people have written Android apps, and that the Android OS is fairly mature, I would start with the assumption that I'd done something wrong. Or perhaps that I was using the API incorrectly. And then I'd spend my time trying to figure out *what I did wrong*, including writing a program that *just* looped over creation and disposal of bitmaps. And if I saw a memory leak with that simple program, then -- and only then -- I'd share it here and ask the other users what I was doing wrong.

Comment: As it is, you're just looking for strangers on the internet to confirm your belief in your own infallibility. And all they can do is guess at what you did wrong.

Comment: @parsifal Wow. Developing is my job, I asked the question for the sake of a discussion and to prevent wasting my time trying to solve an unsolvable issue. Not for my ego. You can write software that buckles under any OS - Windows, Mac OR Android. As my application has grown to a stupid size, I've witnessed many inexplicable glitches. My app became too large to debug a few months ago, for example. As I have stated many times, I'm not asking anyone about my code. I want to know if the people here believe that my theory is plausible, or if they have experienced a similar situation.

Comment: and if they believe that I shouldn't be seeing what I am seeing, then it's the explanation/reasoning that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you do have to worry about GC. Normally what happens is that (like in the case of a gallery), multiple Images are loaded. Images based upon their BMP are loaded and hence stored. Hence their size actually depends on the number of pixels.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890351/high-memory-consumption-by-an-image) is a very similar problem. So adjust the `Image` size and the aspect Ration and all should work well.